# Creationg raw socket but error 10013, then how to develop authority?

Tags: python, sockets

```
sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
```

I just want to create a raw socket, but getting 10013

I ever made C:\Python27 and file get complete-controled authority, but didn't work

and I logged in with the admin role in Win10, what should I do then?

when I used this

```
ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
```

actually I got 0, I am not a admin = =

Answer (score 1):

I sovled it by launching command prompt with admin role.

Then start the .py file in the command line, but I think it's troublesome.